# Iterate through Div and check if the check child element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div tag and inside that Div i have child elements and i want to get all those child elements and check if the child element is Checkbox,If the child element is checkbox then i need that Checkbox to be checked.

```
  <div class="options" >
  <input type="checkbox" class='roles' />
  </div>
```

this is how it looks and there will be unspecified number of checkboxes with same class.

```
    $('.options').children('input').each(function () {
        alert(this.value); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/8qCAd/)**

```
$('.options').children('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    this.checked = true; 
});
```

Or

```
$('.options').children().filter('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    this.checked = true; 
});
```

Comment: +1 for the +1. Its tough to wrou kout when work with too many selectors @RajaprabhuAravindasamy